# salto de linea en un txt en bash

Tags: bash

Quisiera imprimir el procesamiento de un recorrido que se hace por un CSV pero que al leerlo me imprima linea por linea en vertical no en horizontal , en este momento el script me funciona correctamente crea un archivo de texto y me muestra el log de los registros que recorrió, pero sale horizontal y no vertical por cada linea del CSV

```
echo "" > errors.txt
countRow=0
echo "INICIANDO PROCESAMIENTO."
while IFS=, read  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9
do
    let countRow=countRow+1
    echo -e "\n Procesando linea $countRow : \n" >> errors.txt
    echo "_________________________________"
        echo "Nombre del Sitio de Proveedor ->[${col1}]"
    echo "NIT del proveedor -> [${col2}]"
    echo "Email de notificación  -> [${col3}]"
    echo "Grupo de contenido -> [${col4}]"
    echo "CODE   -> [${col5}]"
    echo "COD S1ESA  -> [${col6}]"
    echo "CODE NUEVO  -> [${col7}]"
    echo "ACTIVO  -> [${col8}]"
```

---

efectivamente el script funciona, pero el archivo txt me sale asi:

Procesando linea 1:Supplier no encontrado a partir del nit NIT. Procesando linea 2:

---

lo que quiero es que me salga asi:

Procesando linea 1:Supplier no encontrado a partir del nit NIT.

Procesando linea 2:Supplier etc etc

Comment: no entiendo a qué te refieres con "vertical y no horizontal". He estado probando tu script y todo funciona correctamente, te adjunto una captura de pantalla. [![Aquí la imagen con tu script ejecutado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD7cN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD7cN.png) Si pudieras explicarte mejor, editaré este mensaje intentando dar una respuesta a tu problema.

Comment: @JHABIER, de acuerdo a como ya comentó @Delunado, tu script funciona correctamente, y hace lo que, entiendo, propones. El comando echo repite los argumentos seguidos por un salto de línea. Por otro lado, el entrecomillado con comillas dobles preserva el valor literal de todos los caracteres de dentro de las comillas, con la excepción de $, `, y \, lo que anula el efecto del carácter de escape /.Usas bien la opción -e del comando echo, que activa la interpretación de diversos caracteres de escape (precedidos de barra invertida), entre ellos /n, que imprime un salto de línea.

Comment: ¿Pudiera ser debido a tu versión de bash? ¿Qué shabang tienes definido en la primera línea del script ? ¿Cómo lo ejecutas, con sh script.sh o con ./script.sh? Te propongo, como solución alternativa evitar el uso de echo -e y /n y colocar un echo "" donde necesites un salto de línea.

Answer (score 1):

Probé el script y me funciona, además de ser interesante. Puedes probar a introducir en la cabecera del archivo:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Y ejecutarlo:

```
./tu_script
```

En lugar de:

```
sh tu_script.sh
```

Comment: La cabecera #!/bin/bash define con que se va a utilizar el interprete bash, de otra forma podría simplementar cambiar sh por bash tu_script.sh